# AS3 Error drag and drop multiple draggable object to multiple target

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I want to make the game drag and drop to create multiple draggable objects and it can dragged to multiple targets. But I encountered an error when I drag to the first object that I choose to certain target object is not dragged to the target and then I drag it to another target then succeed. I wanted to fix it. And if you can fix it when the object is dragged to the target and then want to be replaced by another object then the dragged object will be replaced and returned to its original position.

This is a overview the program

[image]

And this is the source codes that I use

```
var xPos:int;
var yPos:int;
var poin:int = 0;
var namaobj1:String;
var namaobj2:String;

addListeners(membaca, menulis, berenang, sepakbola, melukis, memasak, menari, bercocoktanam, beladiri, bermainmusik);

proses.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,proses1);


function getPosition(target:Object):void
{
    xPos = target.x;
    yPos = target.y;
}

function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    getPosition(e.target);

    e.target.startDrag(true);
}

function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName("target2")))
    {
        e.target.x = getChildByName("target2").x;
        e.target.y = getChildByName("target2").y;
        namaobj2 = e.target.name;
    }

    else if (e.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName("target1")))
    {
        e.target.x = getChildByName("target1").x;
        e.target.y = getChildByName("target1").y;
        namaobj1 = e.target.name;
    }
    else
    {
        e.target.x = xPos;
        e.target.y = yPos;
    }


    pil1.text = namaobj1;
    pil2.text = namaobj2;


    e.target.stopDrag();

}

function addListeners(... objects):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);
    }
}
```

I'm using draggable objects by putting addListener function.

I also include his .fla can be downloaded here ( [TEST.FLA](http://wikisend.com/download/267910/test.fla) ) rather you can more easily apply fixed codes

Answer (score 0):

You can add Mouse_UP event in your targets instead of you dragged objects. Then when the MOUSE_UP event is trigged, you will know which objects is your target(e.target) without hitTestObject. The code is as follows:

You could have to set dragged object's mouseEnabled when mouse down, and true after dragged.